# Javascript syntax: inserting the value of a string into a statement

Tags: javascript, string, dom

My question is simple but I can't seem to find the solution. I'm changing my html through javascript. I have a header with an image that I want to change every 3 seconds or so. I made an array with the name of the images I want in my cycle.

For changing the image I made a variable with the name of the image. I then try to insert the value of the string into the follow statement:

```
 imageParent.style.backgroundImage = "url('images/"nextImage".jpg')";
```

But as you see this is completely the wrong syntax. What is the correct syntax for this?

Comment: `"url('images/" + nextImage + ".jpg')"`.

Comment: Thank you! I tried without the spaces, but it didnt work. I was experiencing a bug due to the fact that it was adding .jpg while the files already had a .jpg extension given in the array

Answer (score 4):

What you're trying to do is known as *string concatenation*. In JavaScript it is most easily done using the + operator:

```
"url('images/" + nextImage + ".jpg')"
```

See *The + Operator Used on Strings* at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_operators.asp.

Answer (score 0):

try maybe +nextImage+ instead of nextImage